# Save last Activity state with a Button

Tags: android

I have two Activities: ActivityA and ActivityB.  ActivityA intents to ActivityB which has a button named ClOSE_FOR_NOW. This button should terminate the screen of the app and when relaunching the app, ActivityB should get started rather than the first activity(ActivityA).

Is there any possible suggestion for this ? Any help will be kindly appreciated.
(I'm novice to Android programing)

Comment: use activityforresult when launching ActivityB, and based on result either finish the activity or continue in activity A

Comment: I don't think it's possible, because when the user starts an app by tapping on it's icon, he is in fact starting an Activity.

Comment: tapping the icon starts the launcher activity. However, it can be a "blank" activity that just decides whether to show ActivityA or ActivityB, not?